# Delete entities in batches

Tags: database, entities, batch-operations

Is there a way to organized entity deletion by braking into different batches? I have 700.000 entities associated with pictures that I would like to delete and I would like to perform that into batches.
Any how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Views Bulk Operations, create a View of those entities, and set up a delete operation. It should have configuration options to execute in batches. I have done this before to delete 100,000 records.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations

Comment: Well I can for sure try to get ideas from that module. I need to do it programmatically so I can not use the above module directly.

Comment: @PotneySwitters If you post a new more detailed question, stating that you need to do it programmatically, I'll post a functional answer. You need to add the link to the question as a comment to this answer, so that I can find it.